# Adjust View up with Keyboard show in SwiftUI 3.0 iOS15

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, keyboard-events

I have sign up page with a `VStack` embedded in a `ScrollView` that's embedded in a `VStack`. In the innermost `VStack` I have a series of `TextField`s with a custom `TextFieldStyle`.

The UI of the signup page looks like this:

```
    VStack {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 24) {
                TextField(text: $firstNameText) {
                    Text(.firstNameLabel)
                }
                .textFieldStyle(.customTextfieldStyle())
                TextField(text: $lastNameText) {
                    Text(.lastNameLabel)
                }
                .textFieldStyle(.customTextfieldStyle())
            }
        }
        Spacer()
        Button(action: submit) {
            Text(.nextButtonTitle)
        }
    }
```

[image: Signup Form]

Next, the `customTextfieldStyle` looks like this:

```
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            configuration
                .font(.bodyBook14)
                .padding(.bottom, 16)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(errors.isEmpty ? Color.primary : .errorRed)
                .frame(height: 1)
            ForEach(errors) { error in
                Text(error.title)
                    .font(.bodyBook14)
                    .foregroundColor(.errorRed)
                    .padding(.top, 8)
            }
        }
```

[image: textfield style]

In my custom textfield style I added a rectangle and an error text. The problem I'm having is with this custom style, the rectangle and error messages below the textfield is being covered on focus. the keyboard avoidance doesn't offset enough of the scrollview to display them to the user. The keyboard properly offsets the view just enough to show only the textfield but not the rectangle and error messages. Is it possible to make the keyboard recognize the entire custom textfield style should shift up?

Screenshot below shows how error text is all covered by the keyboard / button.
[image]

Comment: Why don't you post a working version of your code. It's hard to put the pieces together without it.

Comment: Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You probably need to put your`customTextFieldStyle` in an `.overlay()` somewhere, but you have to show a minimal, reproducible example for suggestions on where.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?